# Static IPv4 tunnel with Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, ip, rras, tunneling

Is it possible to create any sort of plain (IPv4, non-ipsec) static tunnel interface using only components of Windows server? Any protocol will do as long as there is reasonable linux support for the other endpoint. IPIP or GRE would be great.

I can sort out my own routing, I don't want sessions, authentication or encryption. I just want the tunnel. It's very easy to write a simple script to to do this with the open-source TUN driver, but I would much rather stick to in-built components if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, PPTP is exactly what you're looking for; the most commonly used implementation of a PPTP server on Linux is poptop. Just be aware that there really is zero security on it.

Comment: It really isn't. Read again, I'm specifically looking for something that doesn't use sessions, and PPTP usually comes wrapped up with all kinds of authentication and encryption which it is difficult to separate from. If I could just set up the underlying GRE tunnel that would be great.

Comment: Then see if Ethernet over IP is a possibility for you... otherwise the only thing I can think of is using NAT.

Comment: Sure, ethernet over IP would work (but it seems weird that Windows would have that but not IP over IP). Where do I go to set that up?

Comment: Also, NAT isn't really a tunnel.

Comment: no, but what you're asking for "isn't really a tunnel" either since you expect it to be stateless. I don't know of any EoIP implementations for windows, and a cursory Google search reveals nothing. There really is no requirement for PPTP to have any sort of authentication whatsoever, you could set a server up that would accept any inbound connections whatsoever and simply filter connections at the firewall perimeter.

Comment: GRE and IP-in-IP - the two I mentioned - certainly are tunnelling protocols and they are stateless. I've maintained large-scale PPTP networks with tens of thousands of users and I know exactly what's involved - but I think I've been very clear with my wording from the start that this is not what I want. It's easy to find Windows implementations of protocols that do this - as I said in my question, it's easy to write a script to do it (which is what I'm using now). If you don't know if this can be done with Windows alone, you don't have the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is one piece of software providing the capability of IPIP / GRE on Windows. It is developed by X4B.

- Page on the software: https://www.x4b.net/kb/WindowsIPIPTunnel
- Forum thread where initial release of non customer specific version is
  made:
  https://vpsboard.com/topic/5240-ipip-tunnel-support-for-windows/